# CSS not not loading in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

styles.css is in static folder only. I have read many other posts in which the problem got solved by placing parallel to static folder.

This is the HTML I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link type="text/css" href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body >
<h1>Hello world!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add folder structure where you store css files. Is it on resources?

Comment: This should work, depending on if you put your CSS file in the right folder. Describe your folder structure in detail in your question (you mentioned `styles.css ` is in the `static` folder, but in the comments on an answer it's suddenly within a folder called `css` within the `static` folder). Additional helpful informaton would be the network log of your web browsers, which you can view through your developer tools. Is the request to fetch your CSS file failing? For now, there's too much missing information so I'm voting to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

Place your `styles.css` file inside the `public` folder in the following directory structure.

```
src
 -> main
    -> java
    -> resources
       -> public
          -> styles.css
```

Comment: I don't see any public folder. I have read many posts and the css file is placed inside css folder. src/main/resources/static/css/styles.css. I even tried placing it parallel to .html file but still the issue is not resolved

Comment: You can have either public or static directories. Spring boot identifies those two folders as the location of static resources. If your css file location is **src/main/resources/static/css/styles.css** as you have mentioned, link tag should be corrected as `href="css/styles.css"`